# I have seen some tutorials that lead you to add a device ID into the valid IDs in the drivers of another device. How does this work?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, compatibility

Let's say I have a generic bluetooth adapter, and the default drivers don't support A2DP. So I download some drivers for another bluetooth adapter that do support A2DP.

First, when I try to install them as drivers for the generic adapter, it says that those are not valid drivers. But if I add the generic device hardware ID into an *.ini of the other device, I can install them as the drivers for the generic device, and it sometimes works!

How is this possible? Do both devices actually use the same hardware? What happens if the hardware is different, does it raise an error somewhere? Does it causes a Kernel panic? Does it make the system unstable?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You won't get A2DP support from an bluetooth adapter that doesn't support it, even if you install drivers that do.

Comment: @TFM Could you explain on that? Isn't A2DP a protocol? Isn't a software update enough to use another protocol?

Comment: Sure. I'm not an expert on bluetooth, but I'm guessing that you need some kind of hardware/firmware support in order to use A2DP. It's like using TCP/IP to communicate on the internet, which the driver (the OS) can do, but to do that in the first place, you need hardware support (a network adapter). So a driver-only solution may not help.